# Margin is ignored in RecyclerView item

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using included layouts in `RecyclerView` item and each `layout_margin` is ignored in my app.(not in layout preview). Why is this happening? `Padding` worked for `TextView` but as I want to position some of the icons which are made from `TextView` and `ImageView`, all margins between them are ignored.

In this example below padding does not have that effect which will "push" icon by `5dp` upwards from the bottom.

**Example of included layout(icon) in my `RecyclerView` item:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="38dp">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/w_icon"
            android:layout_width="9dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_w"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/w_distance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/w_icon"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="5"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextDarkGrey"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATE:**
I've used `wrap_content` for `RelativeLayout`, but I have to change `margins` inside. If I use margins in xml/or i will set them during creation programmatically, it doesnt work in my app. Margins are not set after build.

This is example of `Views` in `HorizontalScrollView` inside my `RecyclerView` item.
This is only for preview purposes. Real `Views` are added to empty `LinearLayout` using `LayoutInflater`:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/scrollable_tracker"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/icon_view_container"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <include layout="@layout/w_layout"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"/>
                        <include layout="@layout/w_arrow"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="-3dp"/>
                        <include layout="@layout/next_layout"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </HorizontalScrollView>
```

**Programmatically adding `margins` by this method:**

```
 private fun setViewMargins(v: View, b: Float){
            val params = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            )
            params.setMargins(left, top, right, convertDpToPixel(b).toInt())
            v.layoutParams = params
        }
```

**Graphical example of my `recyclerView` item:**

[image]

Comment: What do you want?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Please share your main layout too.

Comment: I want to add some sort of recyclerview into recyclerview item. So instead of using adapter I made empty HorizontalScrollView and I'm adding icons depends on data from my child view in onBindViewHolder one by one. There is LinearLayout which is empty at the start and then i add there as many icons as I want. But those icons are custom made in separate xmls. And those margins doesnt work as I use them. Its basically filling of LinearLayout in RecyclerView item with new views by inflating those xml designs.

Answer (score 0):

RelativeLayout is a view group that displays child views in relative positions, Please check [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative)

never take fix   `android:layout_widthight`  and `and android:layout_height`, you also can achieve it using `LinearLayout`, it will be a simple way

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:padding="5dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/w_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_close"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/w_distance"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/w_icon"
    android:text="5"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/></RelativeLayout>
```